# Ruby Project Euler 26, Unable to think of an answer to the problem

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to think of an answer all day long and this is the best I was able to come up with trying to understand from how others did it, but looking over answers with each utilizing different ways dont help me much if I dont know the reasoning and logic behind it, I have been getting 999 when it should be 983

```
numberWithLargestCycle = 0
largestCycleSize = 0

for i in 1..1000
    for j in 1..i
        if ((10 ** j) % i) == 1

            puts "i is #{i}, j is #{j}, #{(10 ** j) % i}"
            if largestCycleSize < j
                numberWithLargestCycle = i
                largestCycleSize = j
            end
        end
    end
end

puts numberWithLargestCycle
```

The Problem I'm trying to solve

> A unit fraction contains 1 in the numerator. The decimal
>   representation of the unit fractions with denominators 2 to 10 are
>   given:
>
> 1/2   =   0.5 1/3 =   0.(3) 1/4   =   0.25 1/5    =   0.2 1/6 =   0.1(6) 1/7  =
>     0.(142857) 1/8  =   0.125 1/9   =   0.(1) 1/10  =   0.1 Where 0.1(6) means 0.166666..., and has a 1-digit recurring cycle. It can be seen that 1/7 has a 6-digit recurring cycle.
>
> Find the value of d < 1000 for which 1/d contains the longest
>   recurring cycle in its decimal fraction part.

Comment: Answer to what? What is your question?

Comment: Is there a problem with your code? Do have difficulties understanding it? What is it?

Comment: It's outputting the wrong number when it should be outputting 983 based on what I understood from other answers, but I dont understand how to aproach this problem at all, what logic i should use, and what would allow me to find the reccuring cyling in a decimal

Comment: @aimenalt _"I dont understand how to aproach this problem at all"_ – so you basically copied the code without understanding what it does and want someone to explain / fix it? (no offence, I'm just trying to understand your problem)

Comment: @Stefan No I did not copy, I clearly said that THAT code was the best > I < came up with , NOTE I did Say  "Come Up with" a solution to how I understood the solutions I read involved it so far and yet I am unable to create the program that I need. If I did indeed copy then Logically I would've gotten the correct answer which I did mention is 983, and not 999. If you want to know specifically how i tried to understand the other answers online it was by outputting significant steps of the program, not copying from the code itself...

Comment: Seriously, It would've been much more helpful for advice or some pointers to how such problem could be approached instead. Many might take stack overflow as to where to have their assignments finished but i have google for that and there exist atleast 10 different solutions for this problem, I'm here to learn from the expertise of this website as a beginer and will one day advance to levels such as yourselves or higher, but we all have to start some where

Comment: @aimenalt did you miss the "no offence" part? I just wanted to know what your actual question is so I can maybe provide some help ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: When readers don't understand your question it's always best to edit the question rather than elaborating in comments. You cannot expect readers wade through comments to try to figure out what you asking, neither should they be required to do so. Also, sometimes comments are deleted, which can make your replies puzzling if not meaningless.

Comment: @Stefan, I didn't mean to seem offended, but I thought it was obvious that the details section of the question was phrased to signify that what I (the code) posted was indeed what I actually came up with, so what you wrote seemed condescending when I consider that, especially coming from a guy with such expertise and experience as yourself.

Comment: @CarySwoveland. Noted, I will write details in a more adequate manor in future posts, Thank you.

Comment: @aimenalt presenting a solution that (almost) works and saying _"unable to think of an answer"_ seems contradictory. That's why I asked if you "copied" the code. Sorry if that seemed condescending, wasn't meant that way :-)

Comment: @Stefan, it's fine mate ;) , its much easier for misunderstandings to happen through just written text, I will work on how I word my sentences from here on out as well. Thank you for noting my blunder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the code does not stop when it actually finds the cycle size; the inner `for` loop keeps executing.

I would **strongly** recommend using meaningful variable names, as this makes it much clearer what the code is actually doing! Also, move the non-obvious code (`((10 ** j) % i) == 1`) into a method, to prevent polluting the "main" code with complex implementation details.

(In fact, that method doesn't always work properly for e.g. `i = 6`, but that's not the main blocker for now...)

Let's consider the case there you're searching for the cycle size of `1/9`:

```
def is_cycle_size?(denominator, cycle_size)
  (10 ** cycle_size) % denominator) == 1
end

denominator = 9
for cycle_size in 1..denominator
  if is_cycle_size?(cycle_size, denominator)
    puts "cycle_size is #{cycle_size}"
  end
end

# Output:
cycle_size is 1
cycle_size is 2
cycle_size is 3
cycle_size is 4
cycle_size is 5
cycle_size is 6
cycle_size is 7
cycle_size is 8
cycle_size is 9
```

Now, the problem has become more apparent. You don't actually want to loop through all possible cycle sizes; you really just want to *get* the cycle size!

In other words, your basic code structure needs to look like this:

```
denominator_with_largest_cycle_size = 0
largest_cycle_size = 0

def find_cycle_size(denominator)
  # Define me!!
end

for denominator in 1..1000
  cycle_size = find_cycle_size(denominator)
  puts "denominator is #{denominator}, cycle size is #{cycle_size}"
  if largest_cycle_size < cycle_size
    denominator_with_largest_cycle_size = denominator
    largest_cycle_size = cycle_size
  end
end
```

(There are other improvements that could be made too; this is only a "minimal" change to your attempt.)

Note that by doing this, you can also test `find_cycle_size` in isolation, e.g. you should be able to run `find_cycle_size(238487)`.

---

Bonus: Once you've figured out how to define the above method, this ruby code can be simplified all the way down to:

```
denominator_with_largest_cycle_size = (1..1000).max_by do |denominator|
  find_cycle_size(denominator)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute-force way of computing the length of a repeating decimal of any rational number `1/m`, `m >= 1` that has a repeating decimal.

Firstly, `1/m` is a terminating decimal or a repeating decimal. It is the former if and only if the prime factors of `m` are `2` and/or `5`. (See, for example, [this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal).) For example, `1.0/40 #=> 0.025` is a terminating decimal since `40 = 2^3 * 5^1`. `2^0` (=`1`), `2^1` and `5^1` also have terminating decimals.

```
require 'prime'

def cycle_length(m)
  return 0 if (Prime.prime_division(m).map(&:first) - [2,5]).empty?
  r = Rational(1,m)
  1.step.find do |n|
    p = (10**n)*r
    p - r == p.to_i.to_r
  end
end

[1,2,3,7,27,40,97].each do |m|
  puts "1/#{m} = #{(1.0/m).round(15).to_s.ljust(17)}: #{cycle_length(m).to_s.rjust(3)}"
end
1/1  = 1.0              :   0
1/2  = 0.5              :   0
1/3  = 0.333333333333333:   1
1/7  = 0.142857142857143:   6
1/27 = 0.037037037037037:   3
1/40 = 0.025            :   0
1/97 = 0.010309278350515:  96
```